# Hide icons encrypted file system partitions in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, fstab, udisks

I've installed Ubuntu 10.04 from the alternate CD.

It has an encrypted root and swap partition.

The root partition is visible in Nautilus as 'File Syste' icon.

There is another icon "216 GB Filesystem". If I click it says: Unable to mount 216 GB Filesystem. /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt is mounted.

Then there is another icon "6.1 GB Swap Space". If I click it it says: Unable to mount 6.1 GB Swap Space. Not a mountable file system.

How can I hide these last two icons?

Partition layout:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
[sudo] password for eddyp: 

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa6e92df4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1       11749    94373811    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2           11871       38914   217219073    5  Extended
/dev/sda3   *       11750       11871      976896   83  Linux
/dev/sda5           11871       38167   211220480   83  Linux
/dev/sda6           38167       38914     5997568   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Mounted as:

```
$ mount
/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
/dev/sda3 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/eddyp/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=eddyp)
/dev/sda1 on /media/S3A6595D003 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be resurrecting a long dead issue but here is an answer.

Add the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/81-udisks.rules` with the following in it:

```
# Hide encrypted hard disk partitions from users
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd*", ENV{ID_BUS}=="ata", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="crypto_LUKS", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
```

This does as it says and hides any partition with a crypto_LUKS file system on a disk attached to the ata bus.

As for the swap partitions showing up, that seems to have been fixed since the time this question was asked.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have an encrypted file system at the moment, but when I do I know where to look.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [the related item in Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/25576/).

For me it looks like there's no 100% working solution at the moment.